# Create test id automatically in RSpec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I am using RSpec to test RESTful API (Not a Rails app). I have plenty of test suites (one API each) and test cases. I am wondering if there is any easy way to create a test id for each test case in the title, so I can easily refer the test case in the ticket or to the others.

e.g.:

```
it "send request to /api/cart with GET - TC001" do
...
end
```

TC001 is the id that I mention.

Or is there any better way for us to refer to any specific test case in RSpec?

Comment: When `rspec` reports a test failure, as well as reporting the test title, it will include the line number where the `it` block starts, and it can be invoked to run just that test e.g. `rspec specs/test.rb:57` (this is the same format as output by rspec). I'm not sure if that would be adequate for your needs, it has been useful to me.

Comment: Basically I need a quick reference to any test cases in the test suite, not only the failure one. And line number is always changing whenever we update the test suite.

Comment: rspec specs -e TC001 would also run that spec (assuming it was in the specs folder)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, RSpec does not provide tools to automatically assign ids to your test cases, but it does provide a couple of mechanisms to make use of them once you have them.

Simplest is to add your test case ids to the `it` first parameter as you have in the question:

```
describe Fixnum do
  it "should support + operator (TC001)" do
    (5 + 8).should == 13
  end
end
```

You will then see the test case id in verbose outputs from `rspec`, and can even filter for specific test case in a way that will work most of the time:

```
$ rspec -f d -e TC001 specs/test.rb

Run options: include {:full_description=>/TC001/}

Fixnum
  should support + operator (TC001)

Finished in 0.00041 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

If that isn't enough for you, then you can take things further by using the test options tags hash to create your own scheme for labelling and managing tests:

```
describe Fixnum do
  it "should support + operator", case_id: 'TC001' do
    (5 + 8).should == 13
  end
end
```

This can be filtered as follows:

```
$ rspec -f d -t case_id:TC001 specs/test.rb

Run options: include {:case_id=>"TC001"}

Fixnum
  should support + operator

Finished in 0.0004 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

But now note that the tag data does not appear in the output. In fact it doesn't appear in any of the output options provided with the `rspec` gem as-is. However, you can access it in RSpec's custom formatters, and in other code that controls test suite behaviour. So you could use this to drive custom reports such as .csvs with test case labels etc, tracking test cases and pass/fail evolution of the cases in a database etc.